# mail() works fine, why i cant receive any mails?

Tags: php, windows, email

I have written the following code in the php and saved as email.php

```
<?php
$to = "gomathi@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "gomathi@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$from) )
echo "Mail Sent to ur id check it .";
else
echo "Mail not Sent";
?>
```

and i changed the configuration file for email to be sent. 
 1) changed the sendmail.ini as follows:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
default_domain= gmail.com
auth_username=gomathii@gmail.com
auth_password=XXXXX
force_sender= gomathi@gmail.com
```

and 2) changed php.ini mail function as follows:

```
SMTP =smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = gomathi@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Now i run the email.php in browser. it returns the "Mail Sent to ur id check it ." . but mail doesn't received from the gomathi@gmail.com .  Why it not received please help me to resolve this.

Comment: How do you config your SMTP server ?

Comment: Either your server isn't configured properly, the SMTP server isn't configured correctly, the email address is incorrect, or it's sent and gone into your junk mail.

Comment: mail returning true doesn't mean that the mail was sent, it only means that the email sending subsystem (such as sendmail) accepted the message as valid.  It could fail to actually arrive at its destination for any number of reasons.

Comment: Have you checked in spam?

Comment: Change sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t" in php.ini

Comment: i found that php.ini and sendmail.ini in folder c:/xamp/php and

Comment: s i check spam, i didn't get any mail

Comment: Different senders & receivers have different configurations. Use a replacement for mails like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and be sure to check for headers correct context when you send mails.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are passing in incorrect parameters to mail and your $headers are never used.

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Consider passing in To & Subject in your headers.

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
```

And adding angle brackets to the email addresses.

The complete working example should be:

```
<?php
$to = "<gomathi@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "<gomathi@gmail.com>";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) )
    echo "Mail Sent to ur id check it .";
else
    echo "Mail not Sent";
?>
```

Also, consider using SSL port 465.